# Running Asyncio and Socketio at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, flask-socketio

I want to run two websockets on in my program, where one communicates to my Raspberry Pi (via websockets) and the other one to my browser via Flask-SocketIO.
Everything runs fine, when I run them in two different python files.
But I can't get them to run in the same file.
This is the Flask-SocketIO Server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

def main():
    print("abc")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=5000)
    print("defg")
```

Output:

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: ...
(12444) wsgi starting up on http://...
```

Noting gets printed.

This is the websockets server: (You can find that piece of code when googleing OCPP Python on mobilityhouses github)

```
import asyncio
import logging
import websockets
from datetime import datetime

from ocpp.routing import on
from ocpp.v201 import ChargePoint as cp
from ocpp.v201 import call_result

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


class ChargePoint(cp):    
# One function was left out to decluster the question

async def on_connect(websocket, path):
    try:
        requested_protocols = websocket.request_headers[
            'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol']
    except KeyError:
        logging.info("Client hasn't requested any Subprotocol. "
                 "Closing Connection")
    if websocket.subprotocol:
        logging.info("Protocols Matched: %s", websocket.subprotocol)
    else:
        # In the websockets lib if no subprotocols are supported by the
        # client and the server, it proceeds without a subprotocol,
        # so we have to manually close the connection.
        logging.warning('Protocols Mismatched | Expected Subprotocols: %s,'
                        ' but client supports  %s | Closing connection',
                        websocket.available_subprotocols,
                        requested_protocols)
        return await websocket.close()

    charge_point_id = path.strip('/')
    cp = ChargePoint(charge_point_id, websocket)

    await cp.start()


async def main():
    server = await websockets.serve(
        on_connect,
        '0.0.0.0',
        9000,
        subprotocols=['ocpp2.0.1']
    )
    logging.info("WebSocket Server Started")
    print("456")
    await server.wait_closed()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("123")
```

Output

```
INFO:root:WebSocket Server Started
456
```

I tried pasting it all in the same document and just doing this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("123")
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=5000)
    print("456")
```

But this just runs the first asyncio.run(main()) and doesnt print 123 etc.
If I switch it up, it will also just run the first .run and than stop.

I tried threading, but that had the same results.
Does anyone know how I can run these two at the same time?

Comment: Flask and Flask-SocketIO do not support asyncio, you cannot mix them in the same application. You can drop Flask+Flask-SocketIO and use python-socketio (which does support asyncio), or else you can drop your asyncio websocket package and use one that works with standard Python. You will also want to consider using the same server for both, the code that you are showing tries to start the WebSocket and the Socket.IO servers on the same thread, and that will not work, instead combine both servers into one, which is fine because each will use different URL endpoints.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I'm using only one websocket now and it's working flawlessly.